# PHP preg_match for one to many

Tags: php, regex

I have to match two columns.
For example ColumnA and ColumnB

```
ColumnA Can have the values  
Apple
Banana
Orange
```

```
ColumnB Can have the values 
Apple
Banana
Orange
Apple_Banana
Apple_Orange
Banana_Apple
Banana_Orange
Apple_Banana_Orange
Apple_Orange_Banana
etc.
```

I tried preg_match and preg_match_all

```
(preg_match('/apple|banana|orange/i',$fruits) == preg_match('/apple|banana|orange/i',$row["fruits"]))
```

```
(preg_match_all('/apple|banana|orange/i',$fruits) == preg_match_all('/apple|banana|orange/i',$row["fruits"]))
```

Example:
If Column A has Apple

It should return rows which contain apple(could be along other fruits)
But it should not return rows which does not contain apple at all.

```
Apple
Apple_banana
Apple_Orange
```

```
But not
Banana
Banana_orange
etc
```

Comment: post the whole relevant snippet of code.

Comment: So you want to see if `$fruits` and `$row["fruits"]` contain `apple|banana|orange`? Or if `$fruits` has a match you want to see if the other has the same match? Please add more details. Also, if both values are coming from DB it's probably easier just to let db do comparison.

Comment: $fruits has to match $row["fruits"]
But it is matching unmatched fruits.
For ex. Apple matches ($fruits) with Apple($row["fruits"]) and also with Banana_orange ($row["fruits"])

Comment: Provide exact example of the issue. This is to abstract as is.

Answer (score 0):

> If Column A has Apple
>
> It should return rows which contain apple

```
$ColumnA = [ "Apple", "Banana", "Orange" ];
$ColumnB = [ "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple_Banana", "Apple_Orange",
"Banana_Apple", "Banana_Orange", "Apple_Banana_Orange", "Apple_Orange_Banana" ];
$row["fruits"] = $ColumnB;
foreach ($ColumnA as $fruits)
    $result[$fruits] = preg_grep("/$fruits/", $row["fruits"]);
print_r($result);
```